# scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack.eigsh is unstable

Tags: numpy, scipy, eigenvector

I run the following code

```
import numpy as np  
from scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack import eigsh


N =3
W = np.random.rand(N,N)

print(W)

Esys2 = eigsh(W, k=2, which = 'LA')
print(Esys2)

Esys = eigsh(W, k=2, which='LA')
print(Esys)
```

and I get the output:

```
[[ 0.21158481  0.20105984  0.60153543]
[ 0.53304312  0.5150105   0.49034533]
[ 0.90599546  0.09468583  0.87709113]]

(array([ 0.24450196,  1.58625052]), array([[ 0.07908241,  0.47701961],
       [-0.77316975,  0.58361601],
       [ 0.62924917,  0.65714887]]))

(array([ 0.31766568,  1.85202346]), array([[ 0.02712824,  0.54350609],
       [-0.85016138,  0.45401711],
       [ 0.52582287,  0.70602379]]))
```

How is that possible? The output seems to be random. All three Eigenvectors cannot be computed(k=2 is max).

Numpy version: 1.11.1
Python version: 3.5.2

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take another look at the docstring for [`eigsh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html).  Note, in particular, two items:

- `eigsh` assumes that the input is a *symmetric* matrix.  Your `W` is not symmetric.  The behavior of the function is undefined if the input array is not symmetric.
- `eigsh` is iterative, and it requires a starting vector for the iteration.  If not given with the `v0` argument, a random vector is chosen.  So you will not necessarily get exactly the same results on repeated calls.